# Trigger a task by API request on Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

is it possible to trigger a SnowFlake TASK using an API? Because I'd like tie up the tasks on my D-Series cycle (It's like a Control-M, workflow automation) as long as I have a windows batch script that uploads XML files to Google Cloud Storage bucket which is the source of them.

PS: I know that I can do this file watcher sync using SnowPipe with storage notification, but I'd like to know if it's possible this option as well.

Comment: My thinking is you can execute SQL externally using the SQL REST API we announced back in June, it can also call a Stored Proc which can have multiple statements inside of it https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks cannot be "triggered" by any method, they can only be run to a schedule.

But as a task only runs either a SQL statement or stored procedure, you can run that SQL statement/stored procedure via any of the APIs that Snowflake supports

Answer (score 0):

dSeries has a Database job type which should be able to call the execute task as SQL.  You would need to use the Snowflake JDBC driver with the Database plugin on the Agent.